# css element child for an id attibute

Tags: css

I had an html elements that would look like this.. it is automatically used an `id` because of the jqueryplugin that used.

```
<p>some text...</p>
<p>some text...</p>
<p id="elmt">some text...</p> <!-- I want to put a background -->
<p id="elmt">some text...</p>
<p id="elmt">some text...</p>
<p id="elmt">some text...</p>
```

is it possible that I can put a child css on this that would look like

```
p#elmt{
 background-color: yellow;
}
p#elmt:first-child{
 background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: ID is used once, Class is used many times.

Answer (score 2):

`:first-child` is a bit tricky, many questions on SO indicate that people think of it in terms of `:first-of-type` (first element matching a selector, while it means the first element inside a parent node).

In this specific case I'd recommend inverting the logic a bit and using

```
 /* set red background for .elmt */
.elmt {
    background-color: red;
}
/* set yellow background for .elmt preceded ba another .elmt 
   - which is all except the first one */
.elmt + .elmt {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qQ8dm/5/

Answer (score 1):

Since `id` is unique, you must use class instead:

```
<p class="elmt">some text...</p> <!-- I want to put a background -->
<p class="elmt">some text...</p>
<p class="elmt">some text...</p>
<p class="elmt">some text...</p>
```

Then you can use `.` to target element by class:

```
p.elmt {
    background-color: yellow;
}
p.elmt:first-child {
    background-color: red;
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8yNfm/)**

Comment: Note that in the case in the question, `p.elmt:first-child` wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this using `id` attributes, use `class` attribute,

#### Check [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gj7YL/)

id use individual identifier, where as class is use for allow to multiple select.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to @pawel answer you can use the `not` selector.

The first answer has better support but I add this for reference.

**CSS**

```
p:not(.elmt) + .elmt {
 background-color: yellow;
}

.elmt {
    background-color: #00f;
}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/qQ8dm/7/)